# Import a text file by converting repeating groups of lines into columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

My data file looks like

```
1234567 7654321

TEXT ABOUT STUFF
ON MULTIPLE LINES
NOT SURE HOW MANY

1234567 7654321

TEXT ABOUT STUFF
ON MULTIPLE LINES
NOT SURE HOW MANY
```

The only thing for certain is a new record starts with 2 sets of numbers that are 7 characters long. The numbers are also on a new line and appear as my sample data above.

I am using SQL Server Express on Windows 8.

Ultimately I need the first group of numbers in a column, 2nd group in another column and the remainder of the text in the 3rd column.

Comment: I also don't mind writing a C# application if that will make it easier.

Comment: Well, c# would be much more straightforward.  Is there always a blank line before and after the lines with the two numbers?

Comment: Yes there is always a blank line before and after numbers

Answer (score 0):

This is the realm of [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load).  The SQL Server was of doing this is to use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx).

Comment: ETL is provided through Integration Services (SSIS), isn't it? But more specifically, how would you use it to extract only rows matching the pattern given?